# How do I change JPanel inside a JFrame on the fly?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

To put it simple, there's a simple java swing app that consists of JFrame with some components in it. One of the components is a JPanel that is meant to be replaced by another JPanel on user action.

So, what's the correct way of doing such a thing? I've tried

```
panel = new CustomJPanelWithComponentsOnIt();
parentFrameJPanelBelongsTo.pack();
```

but this won't work. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your use case, seems perfect for [CardLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

In card layout you can add multiple panels in the same place, but then show or hide, one panel at a time.

Comment: When using CardLayout, keep in mind that the preferred size for the panel that uses it will be the size of the LARGEST panel in the layout. If you want the space to be reclaimed, you will want to use setVisible(false) and setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 0,0 ) ) to hide a component.

Comment: I hadn't heard of CardLayout before.  Thanks - was perfect for something I needed to do.

Comment: Yes. This is the proper way. Maybe the best.

Answer (score 29):

1) Setting the first Panel:

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(new JPanel());
```

2)Replacing the panel:

```
frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
frame.getContentPane().add(new JPanel());
```

Also notice that you must do this in the Event's Thread, to ensure this use the [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) or the [SwingWorker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Answer (score 23):

```
frame.setContentPane(newContents());
frame.revalidate(); // frame.pack() if you want to resize.
```

Remember, Java use 'copy reference by value' argument passing. So changing a variable wont change copies of the reference passed to other methods.

Also note `JFrame` is very confusing in the name of usability. Adding a component or setting a layout (usually) performs the operation on the content pane. Oddly enough, getting the layout really does give you the frame's layout manager.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your reply. I'm not aiming to replace the contentpane, just a jpanel placed on it (like frame.add(jpanel1), frame.add(jpanel2), frame.add(jpanel3)). Could you plz suggest a sane solution in code?

Comment: Hey John,

Your use case, seems perfect for CardLayout. 

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

In card layout you can add multiple panels in the same place, but then show or hide, one panel at a time.

Comment: You may run into problems when using the setContentPane() method.  I had cases where all (custom) cursors not showing up anymore after calling it.

Answer (score 8):

Hope this piece of code give you an idea of changing jPanels inside a JFrame.

```
public class PanelTest extends JFrame {

        Container contentPane;

        public PanelTest()  {
           super("Changing JPanel inside a JFrame");
           contentPane=getContentPane();
        }

        public void createChangePanel() {
           contentPane.removeAll();
           JPanel newPanel=new JPanel();
           contentPane.add(newPanel);
           System.out.println("new panel created");//for debugging purposes
           validate();
           setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

On the user action:

// you have to do something along the lines of

```
myJFrame.getContentPane().removeAll()
myJFrame.getContentPane().invalidate()

myJFrame.getContentPane().add(newContentPanel)
myJFrame.getContentPane().revalidate()
```

Then you can resize your wndow as needed.

Answer (score 4):

```
Game game =  new Game();
getContentPane().removeAll(); 
setContentPane(game);  
getContentPane().revalidate(); //IMPORTANT
getContentPane().repaint();    //IMPORTANT
```

Comment: Hi Adnane Afifi, consider adding some explanation to your solution.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on how its going to be used.  If you will want to switch back and forth between these two panels then use a CardLayout.  If you are only switching from the first to the second once and (and not going back) then I would use [telcontar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518/telcontar)s suggestion and just replace it.  Though if the JPanel isn't the only thing in your frame I would use 
[remove(java.awt.Component)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove(java.awt.Component)) instead of removeAll.

If you are somewhere in between these two cases its basically a time-space tradeoff.  The CardLayout will save you time but take up more memory by having to keep this whole other panel in memory at all times.  But if you just replace the panel when needed and construct it on demand, you don't have to keep that meory around but it takes more time to switch.

Also you can try a JTabbedPane to use tabs instead (its even easier than CardLayout because it handles the showing/hiding automitically)

Answer (score 1):

The other individuals answered the question.  I want to suggest you use a JTabbedPane instead of replacing content.  As a general rule, it is bad to have visual elements of your application disappear or be replaced by other content.  Certainly there are exceptions to every rule, and only you and your user community can decide the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I was having exactly the same problem!! Increadible!! The solution I found was:

1. Adding all the components (JPanels) to the container;
2. Using the setVisible(false) method to all of them;
3. On user action, setting setVisible(true) to the panel I wanted to
   show.

```
// Hiding all components (JPanels) added to a container (ex: another JPanel)
for (Component component : this.container.getComponents()) {
      component.setVisible(false);
}
```

```
// Showing only the selected JPanel, the one user wants to see
panel.setVisible(true);
```

No revalidate(), no validate(), no CardLayout needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**: My component does not appear after I have added it to the container.

You need to invoke [revalidate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) and [repaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) **after adding** a component **before it will show up** in your container.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/problems.html

Answer (score 1):

The layout.replace() answer only exists/works on the GroupLayout Manager.

Other LayoutManagers (CardLayout, BoxLayout etc) do NOT support this feature, but require you to first RemoveLayoutComponent( and then AddLayoutComponent( back again.  :-)  [Just setting the record straight]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add both panel at frame creation, then change the visible panel by calling setVisible(true/false) on both.
When calling setVisible, the parent will be notified and asked to repaint itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Frame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    remove(previouspanel); //or getContentPane().removeAll();

    add(newpanel); //or setContentPane(newpanel);

    invalidate(); validate(); // or ((JComponent) getContentPane()).revalidate();

    repaint(); //DO NOT FORGET REPAINT

}
```

Sometimes you can do the work without using the revalidation and sometimes without using the repaint.My advise use both.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method **pack()** after setting the `ContentPane`, (`java 1.7`, maybe older) like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(); 
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(); 
....
frame.setContentPane(panel1);
frame.pack();
...

frame.setContentPane(panel2);
frame.pack();
...
```