# Refresh JPanel when someone insert new data in database?

Tags: java, mysql, jpanel, refresh

how can I refresh dynamically Jpanel when someone insert new item in database(database isnt local)? For exemple someone with another pc insert new row in a table of mt db .. i see it only if i close and reopen my app.. sorry for my eng.

Comment: More info? how do you put your data into the jpanel, wich db?

Comment: I create a sort of Chat with more JLabel that go in Panel

Comment: This thread might help you to fix your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218155/how-do-i-change-jpanel-inside-a-jframe-on-the-fly

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nameOfPanel.revalidate();
nameofPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: I do this but work only if I reopen my app, is not dynamically