# Switching jpanels with a jbutton

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a login system implanted already in a jpanel with a database connection, how can I switch to another jpanel with a jbutton so people can register?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218155/how-do-i-change-jpanel-inside-a-jframe-on-the-fly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change JPanel inside a JFrame on the fly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218155/how-do-i-change-jpanel-inside-a-jframe-on-the-fly)